# Use wifi as the WAN port of a router?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

How would you configure a router to use a wireless signal as their "WAN" port? Meaning, they don't bridge to the existing network but rather create their own private subnet.

[image]

Comment: Your question will remain closed as long as it contains an answer to your own question.

Comment: @Ramhound: I moved the troublesome link to my answer, so this post can be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

Using
[Wifi-as-WAN](https://customer.cradlepoint.com/s/article/What-is-the-difference-between-WiFi-as-WAN-and-Wireless-Client-mode)
is an odd setup, but is possible.
Its availability is totally dependent on the router's firmware.
It may also cause some limitations on using this router as
a wireless access-path for client wireless devices.

Some [Cradlepoint routers](https://cradlepoint.com/products/endpoints/)
have this capacity, as described in the article
[Configure WiFi as WAN on Cradlepoint Routers](https://usatcorp.com/faqs/configure-wifi-wan-cradlepoint-router/?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=52ba0422c9d4df12d3873cce730a69f8d7194fc5-1624562345-0-AY7BUa1VBYXCzBx_Al12cdmTfKadBJKNqAorrl97BpsHbF3wrU-YgzYapRturglG-V3A0H2fZctSaLVxeGe1XO9vYlIJ52lYj-o1ex3G7K9iyg_h0YOpv90i2Z5urVCxDPSct-UjXuNZZ_se8mFTNGu2j47XNOLH1MFQ3nZm1aTuM8T8WyEewjFvFVB0TU97FyQnyr2_oY96dRsSJQoS0iXugMVRyRIe7eZgHZsyjvLK3iLVhSLlwxhbBB_3NQ-cpRGNZPlDbUIczQepXmAoj0GKon3lMLMSBLCVWwx7hRfhj5OYzRmYyHrlmRa9n-hiFIbted9Fwcalf678u9j07NpLMHkf-hkP4IKvsYQQG_K-0KvmqLAiH5ttfVfX9iPapOcIF7L5MrSI_ZyBCjGoUKphBijDxHAwcwscfm2Vngl2rsYYuQBXqVzI_TAhvzeF92I9ygQcl1t0GkJw9NJpAcUK5t8cpleWx6yWH9xeXpUSulDLvqPdLpVGCQuFGJKpdxNQjgcomyP61H-3-H5ovBo).

I wish to emphasis that I'm not recommending here any product,
just giving an example. I have never used or seen any
Cradlepoint router in my life.
Wifi-as-WAN does exist, but it's up to you to find your router.

As another example, see
[OpenWRT documentation for this type of setup](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wifi/connect_client_wifi).

Comment: do you know if dd-wrt or OpenWRT support this odd setup? edit, looks like openwrt does https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wifi/connect_client_wifi

Comment: Seems odd that this was closed as a shopping recommendation.